# problem with PDF file and Document Viewer

Tags: pdf

I downloaded this file from IEEE website using my institute subscription,

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx5/4629386/6365209/06042853.pdf?tp=&arnumber=6042853&isnumber=6365209

my Document Viewer version 3.6.0 terminates every time I cross page number 4, any help or reason why this happens?

I tried changing the extensions to odt and doc, LibOffice draw opens the files, but they aren't clear,

Comment: I downloaded it twice, but there is no change in the outcome, when I changed the extension of the file to .doc the entire document is visible but it isn't clear.

Comment: LibreOffice draw opens the file after renaming the file, I tried both .odt , .doc extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

Open **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for PDF reader. There are quite a number of them you can try them one at a time and see if any of them can read the file. If not you can uninstall them using **Ubuntu Software Center**.

**Option 2**

You can download Adobe Reader from Their [official website](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=10&platform=Unix). The page will take you to a FTP site and you have to drill down the directory structure to find the latest .deb file. As of this writing it was

ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.1/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i386linux_enu.deb

Download the file and double click on it to open it in **Ubuntu Software Center**. Click on the Install button and follow instructions if needed.

Best of luck.